# Linux netconsole with bridged interface

Tags: linux, networking, bridge

I'm attempting to enable `netconsole` on my home PC, however encountering some trouble with my bridged LAN and Wi-Fi.

1. If I don't specify an interface name, it fails as follows:

   ```
   $ sudo modprobe netconsole netconsole=6666@192.168.0.1/,6666@192.168.0.2/A0:F3:C1:FF:4C:70 
   modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'netconsole': No such device
   ```

   dmesg output:

   ```
   netpoll: netconsole: local port 6666
   netpoll: netconsole: local IPv4 address 192.168.0.1
   netpoll: netconsole: interface 'eth0'
   netpoll: netconsole: remote port 6666
   netpoll: netconsole: remote IPv4 address 192.168.0.2
   netpoll: netconsole: remote ethernet address a0:f3:c1:ff:4c:70
   netpoll: netconsole: eth0 doesn't exist, aborting
   netconsole: cleaning up
   ```

   It tries to look for `eth0` and fails, most likely because systemd renamed it to `enp9s0`.
2. If I specify the new interface name explicitly:

   ```
   $ sudo modprobe netconsole netconsole=6666@192.168.0.1/enp9s0,6666@192.168.0.2/A0:F3:C1:FF:4C:70
   modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'netconsole': Device or resource busy
   ```

   dmesg output:

   ```
   netpoll: netconsole: local port 6666
   netpoll: netconsole: local IPv4 address 192.168.0.1
   netpoll: netconsole: interface 'enp9s0'
   netpoll: netconsole: remote port 6666
   netpoll: netconsole: remote IPv4 address 192.168.0.2
   netpoll: netconsole: remote ethernet address a0:f3:c1:ff:4c:70
   netpoll: netconsole: enp9s0 is a slave device, aborting
   netconsole: cleaning up
   ```

   OK, so it doesn't like that `enp9s0` is part of a bridge.
3. Let's try it with the bridge:

   ```
   $ sudo modprobe netconsole netconsole=6666@192.168.0.1/br0,6666@192.168.0.2/A0:F3:C1:FF:4C:70 
   modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'netconsole': Unknown error 524
   ```

   dmesg output:

   ```
   netpoll: netconsole: local port 6666
   netpoll: netconsole: local IPv4 address 192.168.0.1
   netpoll: netconsole: interface 'br0'
   netpoll: netconsole: remote port 6666
   netpoll: netconsole: remote IPv4 address 192.168.0.2
   netpoll: netconsole: remote ethernet address a0:f3:c1:ff:4c:70
   netpoll: (null): wlp6s0 doesn't support polling, aborting
   netconsole: cleaning up
   ```

   Looks like it tries to set up all interfaces that are part of the bridge, and fails at the Wireless interface.

Does a solution exist?

Comment: At least on kernel 4.14 `netconsole` loads fine on my `bridge0` interface.

Comment: It appears to be device driver specific, rather than because of the bridge. Here's how it was "fixed" on a odroid xu4 ethernet interface: https://github.com/hardkernel/linux/commit/a98b3e4734f17b4e4932a9a8d0d4fb1867ee17f2#diff-d45f6c5dfa1088acc4fb00e7636dbba7 . I don't know if the same technique (adding a stub function to "implement" the missing feature) would work for this case. Feel free to test.